# UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData creates PDFs unreadable by Acrobat

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Im creating PDF's from iOS using a ordinary code block.

```
NSMutableData *pdfdata = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:2048];
CGRect newf = CGRectMake(0, 0,1024,1024);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfdata,newf,nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

//rendering code

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

iOS and OS X read these PDF's just fine but Acrobat claims they are damaged and unreadable. The interesting thing is that doing a duplicate in `Preview` unmangles them and makes them readable by Acrobat again.

By diff-ing the two versions I can see that the OS X PDF encoder has added a bunch of stuff (its binary so no idea what)

Anyone know the secret sauce to making my PDF's Acrobat compatible again.

**EDIT**

[Broken file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgdtii6zo68uypd/mindmap-2.pdf?dl=0) - will not open in Acrobat

Comment: ... added to the end, with all the data beforehand identical to what it was?

Comment: no some stuff in the middle in a few places. but lots of identical sections

Comment: Can you share a sample broken PDF?

Comment: file added to question

Comment: I just wanted to describe the issue but @iPDFdev beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document starts with a block of 2048 bytes filled with zero and this damages all offsets in the file.

Create an empty NSMutableData without initial length and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Stunning, Thanks so much. I had always assumed the NSMutableData ref was completely overwritten from zero by the encoder.